# Neatest way to walk through a List of pointers?

Tags: c

I have two version of the same function and i am not sure which of the two i should pick. They do the same thing, but i wonder if there is a "right way" to do it or if it is only a question of aesthetics.

```
//both functions have to start at the second element
int multiFileHandler_1(char **files, int filenumber)
{

filenumber = filenumber - 1;
*files++;
while(filenumber--)
{
printf("%s\n", *files); 
fileOpen(*files);   
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



int multiFileHandler_2(char **files, int filenumber)
{
    char **file;
    for (file = &files[1]; *file != '\0'; file++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *file);  
        fileOpen(*file);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I read have read a few texts about code readability and a few leaned towards using `for` since it places all the important information into one block. But the `while` version looks a tiny bit neater.

EDIT: Ah, stackoverflow is quite a learning experience. Shows me how much of a n00b i am. :P

Comment: If you think the `while` version looks neater, use the `while` version.

Comment: The two loops do different things.

Comment: `for (file = &files[1]; *file != '\0'; file++)` needs the guaranteed delimiter in the last char* field '\0' (otherwise it runs out of bounds), which is not necessary in the first version. So no aesthetics but syntactic differences.

Comment: Yeah, you are comparing apples and pears, version 2 does not use the filenumber argument. Anyway, I'd prefer the for version which makes it more obvious you are doing a complete and regular array traversal. And please avoid to hide the progression mechanism *file++ within a function call.

Comment: I don't see a fileOpen() on the first method. Is this intended?

Comment: Yves: I see what you mean, i had to re-read the original a few times myself before i got it. Serves me right for cobbling my code together from different other peoples code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first loop you depend on a second argument, `filenumber`, in order to iterate through the list. In the second example you use a null-terminator in order to identify the end of the list, therefore eliminating the need for a second parameter.

I'd prefer the second example with the `for` loop. To me it looks cleaner (although it can still be improved as others have pointed out.) Although this also means it depends on that null-terminator, and if it's not present you have problems.

Comment: The good thing is that i know that in that case it is null-terminated. I have to keep in mind that it will be in all the other cases i might use it for.

Comment: You should stick to one way of maintaining the list length. Null-terminated is OK, but then throw away `filenumber`. Else, everywhere you modify the list you'll have two things to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is NULL-terminated, I think that the right (and aesthetic) way is to use this, so I was choosing the second way.

BTW, You probably meant `*file != NULL` instead of `*file != '\0'` (because `*file` is a pointer). You can write just `*file`.

Comment: It's only useful for obfuscation, but `*file != '\0'` is also a correct way to write the condition. `'\0'` is just a circumspect `0`, which is a null pointer constant in pointer contexts.

Comment: @DanielFischer No it is not correct, because NULL might not necessarily evaluate to the integer literal 0. [Check the C FAQ.](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html)

Comment: More knowledge with every moment! =)

Comment: @Lundin That's not the important thing. The important issue is that an integer constant expression with value 0 evaluates to a null pointer in a pointer context - 6.3.2.3 (3).

Comment: @DanielFischer you are right, of course. I said it for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, but suppose the code had an accidental bug: `**file != NULL` would hopefully give an error/warning, but `**file != '\0'` would be valid if file was an integer type.

Comment: Oh, sure. Comparing a pointer to `'\0'` outside the IOCCC is a reason for some serious trout-slapping. Not everything that is correct is also good ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the array size is determined.
It's best to stick to one way of doing it, and not mix two. So if your function gets a filenumber parameter, it should use it.
It is OK to determine the end of the list by a null, but then you don't need the size parameter.

So I recommend a variation of your first method, which seems clearer to me:

```
for (int i=0; i<filenumber; i++) {
   printf("%s\n", files[i]);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip the first element always, and know that it's not NULL, but the remainder is NULL terminated, I would do it like this:

```
for (files++; *files != NULL; files++)
{
    printf("%s\n", *files);
}
```